# JQuery Autocomplete: Using a key and label local JS Array? help!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm making a simple iPhone web page that lists around 200 medical terms and their definitions. I'm using JQuery autocomplete to allow the user to dynamically search the terms, and when they tap the term they want I want to display the term's definition right below. I need help setting up a JS array with both the term and the definition at once.

Currently, I have an array loaded as such :

```
var terms = [
        "Abdomen",
        "Ability",
        "Abolish",
etc...
```

What I would prefer however is if I knew how to load a term and its definition in an array like this:

```
terms['Abdomen'] = 'stomach, stomach area, belly, tummy';
terms['Ability'] = 'skill';
terms['Abolish'] = 'end, do away with, get rid of';
```

Anyway, at the end of the `terms` array list I activate the autocomplete code as such:

```
$( "#terms" ).autocomplete({ source: terms,});
    $( "#terms" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 2 });
    $( "#terms" ).autocomplete({ delay: 0 });
    $( "#terms" ).autocomplete({ select: function(event, ui) 
    { 
        var myDiv1 = document.getElementById("content");
        myDiv1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ui.item.label));
    }
```

Right now all this does is when the user taps on the term in the dropdown list, the term itself which is known as `ui.item.label` just gets written to the `content` div. What I want is for the term's definition to be written. How do I set this up in JQuery where I can have the autocomplete select function simply write the definition and not the term/label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/custom-data.html) example you should be able to add all the properties you want in your source data array and be able to access them on the select event.

So your source data array could look like this:

```
var terms = [
    {label : "Abdomen", desc: "stomach, stomach area, belly, tummy"},
    {label : "Ability", desc: "skill"},
    {label : "Abolish", desc: "end, do away with, get rid of"}
etc...
```

and then in your select event definition do this:

```
$( "#terms" ).autocomplete({ select: function(event, ui) 
{ 
    var myDiv1 = document.getElementById("content");
    myDiv1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ui.item.desc));
}
```

So the difference is that you can then use `ui.item.desc` instead of `ui.item.label` like you were using before.

Answer (score 0):

Create another separate js array with the term as the string index, like you show. Call it something else like `definitions`, not `terms`. Then when you want to append the "content" div, create a new  like this

```
var newDefinition = definitions[ui.item.label];
```

And that will call the terms' definition. Then use the appendChild function like you were just doing.